# Error Resources not found on Xamarin Forms droid

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin solution with a iOS project working, now i'm triying to do the same on android. So i created a new project android, install the nugets, and set the references, and this happens:

```
resource integer/google_play_services_version not found. (APT0000)
```

In the path obj/debug/android..., so i delete the obj and bin folder, build and got this:

```
resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog' not found.
style attribute 'attr/colorAccent' not found.
resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar' not found.
style attribute 'attr/windowNoTitle' not found.
style attribute 'attr/windowActionBar' not found.
style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary' not found.
style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark' not found.
style attribute 'attr/colorAccent' not found.
style attribute 'attr/windowActionModeOverlay' not found.
```

I deleted the obj and bin folder, the .local/share/xamarin too, clean and rebuild. And the packages are this:
[image]

And this is my style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Login" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/SplashImage</item>        
        <!-- This is for the EditText Color lines-->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/greenBase</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/greenBase</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="displayOptions">showTitle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
        <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
         <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/greyBase</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/greenBase</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/greenBase</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/greyBase</item>
        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/greenBase</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base"/>

    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MainTheme.BaseLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
         <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/greyBase</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/greenBase</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/greenBase</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/greyBase</item>
        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I don't know if i'm making something wrong to make the android app. What more can i try?

Comment: Add `<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YourApiKey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in **Manifest.xml**

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/170350/xamarin-forms-build-failed-error-apt0000-resource-integer-google-play-services-version-not-found

Comment: A lot of your packages are not latest and may be causing the issue why don't you try updating them once

Comment: I updated all the packages, still the same errors.

Comment: Did you test it on real device ?

Comment: Yes, on debug and release, on my android phone and emulator, can't compile cause these errors

Comment: I know this is absolutely ridiculous but I get the issues above when deleting bin + obj. Simple solution is to restart visual studio.

Comment: If i do that, the error show me : "package com.google.android.gms.location does not exist" on obj/Debug/android... i restore the nugets, but the only solution to solve these error was deleting the obj and bin

Comment: Could you please share your styles.xml file? Also is your Visual Studio updated? And can you try to create a new solution and check to see if the android works when you build it?

Comment: Yes, will edit the question, and i tried creating a new solution and it works fine. it's only in this scenario, cause i have the project in iOS and try to make the project for android